# CSS to make a grid of cells that each fill 100% height of their row

Tags: html, css, grid, height

[image: Example screenshot]

As shown in the example above, I'm trying to create a grid of boxes/cells. I want it to look nicer than the screenshot, and **I want the bottom of each cell extend down** to align with the bottom of the tallest cell in the row. I know there are about a millions posts to solve 100% height problems but none of them seem to work for this case.

Requirements:

- **No background images**
- **No javascript**
- Must work with the following Doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">` (Drupal 7)
- But, I'm very flexible with the markup and CSS, for example, I'm fine with adding extra clear divs or even re-doing the whole thing with tables.

Here's the code I used to make the screenshot above:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Here is a grid of several cells. We want each cell to extend down to the bottom of the row.</div>
  <div class="cell">This cell it too short. </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">This cell should extend down to the bottom.</div>
  <div class="cell">We don't want to use background images or javascript. But the markup and CSS can be made however is best. Each row should contain cells of equal size.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  clear: both;
}

.cell {
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the actual content is, but is there any reason you *aren't* using a `<table>`? This seems like the common layout question of how to get [equal height](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height) columns, does that sound accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what did it for me...

[image]

HTML:

```
<table><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Here is a grid of several cells. We want each cell to extend down to the bottom of the row.</td>
    <td>This cell it too short. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This cell should extend down to the bottom.</td>
    <td>We don't want to use background images or javascript. But the markup and CSS can be made however is best. Each row should contain cells of equal size.</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: -10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

td {
  background: #CCC;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to get in the habit of not using tables for responsive reasons, but when you are looking for a table, use a table!

Answer (score 3):

You could perfectly achieve this with `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` (unless you need to support IE7 and lower):

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/nFeCw/

```
.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  display:table-cell;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot: `display:table-*`. So obvious! +1... Oddly enough, OP says "I'm fine with ... re-doing the whole thing with tables." which would of course, give you the wider browser support and make this beyond simple.

Comment: This CSS does not display space between the cells. Margin doesn't work. However if you wrap the whole thing in a an element with "border-spacing" then it will work.