# Adaptive grid layout with cells of different height

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I have a grid with cells that are generated like so:

```
 <style>   
.calWrapper{
 width:200px;
 float:left;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
            echo "<div class='calWrapper'><h3 id='cal-$i-label'></h3>";
            echo "<div class='calendar' id='cal-$i'>Loading...</div>";
            echo "</div>";
    }?>
```

After the page loads, a bunch of AJAX requests are made that fill the .calendar divs are filled with, surprise, calendars! They lay themselves out in a nice grid with a varied number of columns based on how wide it is. However, when each month is a different height I end up with this mess: [image: calendar mess]

I know I can arrange them into a grid with `display: table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`, however because the number of cells per row change depending on the width of the viewport, there is no clearly defined 'row'. Basically, I need the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672276/css-to-make-a-grid-of-cells-that-each-fill-100-height-of-their-row), but without using `display:table-*`.

I have tried explicitly setting the height of the calWrapper div, however on a small month it leaves an insane amount of white space and on a large month it is incomparable with the fact that the events displayed on that month make the calendar arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I was going to suggest Bootstrap, but I am not sure how far you are into your site architecture, so instead, use the basic principles of Bootstrap `class="row"`but instead of using `display:table` use `display:inline-block` That way you can still have the dynamic height you need and avoid this wrapping issue.

I would define the amount of calendars you are going to have per row (4 in this case) and class that row with a `class="row"` and give it this css.

```
.row {
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:20px auto;
    clear:both;
 }
```

See the **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raLobE)**

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I am indeed using Bootstrap, but found that its tabling and grid layout facilities did not play nice with some legacy code I was having to use.